# Date Indicators SRSS

Tags: sql, sql-server, indicator

I have this query

```
SELECT DateRevised, 
CASE
WHEN DateRevised BETWEEN DateAdd("m",-1,DateRevised) AND GETDATE() Then '2'
When DateRevised BETWEEN DateAdd("m",-3,DateRevised) AND DateAdd("m",-2,DateRevised) Then '0'
End "Indicator"
FROM UpdateTable
```

What I want to do is to create another column called Indicator, so I can then go to Report Builder and put a green indicator when the date is from last month to Date, and a red indicator when it's older than a month.

I am having trouble to create the query as it is showing in all the rows the value "2" without following the rule that should be 2 if it is from last month to date.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo. You should use getDate() in your DATEADD function:

```
SELECT DateRevised, 
CASE
WHEN DateRevised BETWEEN DateAdd("m",-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() Then '2'
When DateRevised BETWEEN DateAdd("m",-3,GETDATE()) AND DateAdd("m",-2,GETDATE()) Then '0'
End "Indicator"
FROM UpdateTable
```